# Executing a JMeter Sampler even on error

Tags: jmeter

Consider the following simplified scenario:

[image: A sample JMeter Test Plan]

Very simple user journey where `Action 1` and `Action 2` is executed multiple times. Currently, action to be taken after a Sampler error is set to *Continue* which means it will go on sending requests even when a step has failed (which is not very realistic) but it will execute the `Pacing`.

Now, if I change the setting to *Start Next Thread Loop* and when say, `Action 2` fails, it will bypass Pacing (which is again not what I want).

[image: start next thread loop]

Is there a way to execute the `Pacing` above before exiting the loop even when *Start Next Thread Loop* is selected? The Pacing should be executed regardless of failure of any action (there could be many) above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the thread to continue on Thread Group level go for [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler instead, it has the same functionality in terms of starting over the next loop, but it can be applied locally

[image: JMeter Test Action Sampler]

Your test plan outline should look as:

- Login
- Loop Controller

  - Action 1
  - [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) with condition of `${__groovy(vars.get('JMeterThread.last_sample_ok').equals('false'),)}`

    - Pacing
    - Test Action
  - Action 2
  - Pacing
- Last Action
- Logout

`${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` is a [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) which holds previous sampler result, in the above script it is being used to check whether `Request 1` is successful or not

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, imagine having to apply these to every sampler in the test suite. A simpler way would be to place `Pacing` at the begining of the Loop. Any other ideas?

Comment: I suggest you stop suggesting me anything, moreover you didn't mention this "every sampler" requirement in the *initial* question version. If you want the clause to be applied to each and every sampler you need to go for a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), i.e. [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and implement your "pacing" "logic" there in [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Comment: I was just curious if any other appraoch existed or was possible in jmeter. For example: if I mark a particular sampler *mandatory* let it be executed regardless of the status above OR  may be place the `Pacing` bit somewhere that it gets triggered even on error. There are various way to do things.